# Post json to django rest framework API with jquery-ajax not working

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

i have the models:

```
class Publicacion(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Estado(models.Model):
    publicacion = models.OneToOneField(Publicacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    texto = models.TextField()
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='estados', blank=True, null=True)
```

so my json should be like

{
    "estado": {
        "texto": "",
        "imagen": image
    }
}

my jquery ajax is

```
$$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
    },
    url: "url",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({"estado":{"texto": "text", "imagen": dataImg}}),
    success: function (data) { 
        myApp.alert("Correcto");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

but when i send it with i have a 400 bad request response, server says that "estado" is required, any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried it without the `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: yes, with postman that json works perfectly

Comment: just for grins, try setting`processData: false`

Comment: error 415 unsupported media type

Comment: I'd check that JSON request and send it to http://requestb.in/ to see if it's created correctly. Or debug it with django or http debug proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt, *JSON.stringify()* turns a Javascript object into JSON text, so as you are building on the fly, you could send it only like this:

```
data: {estado:{texto: "text", imagen: dataImg}},
```

In other case you need to do this (you were missing *contentType*):

```
dataType: 'JSON',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(yourObject),
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to explicitly set the `content_type` parameter, if you let jquery handle it you can send the back end a normal assoc array and it will work fine

```
$.ajax("domain/end_point",{
    type: "POST",
    data : {"details": "my assoc data"},
    crossDomain: true,
    // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```